# Is there any package in pandas to calculate mean of selected part of values of column based on other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate mean of dataframe column based on other columns , for example i have column a ,c d and column e contains value for mean. if column 'a' 6 rows have value then calculate mean of 6 rows in column e and only give one value.next check column c if have value then calculate mean corresponding value and then check column c and do same.

i tried this piece of code but its not giving my desired results

```
df['mean']=df['e'].rolling(window=6, min_periods=6).mean()
```

original dataframe:

[image]

desired output:

[image]

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[0] * 6 + [np.nan] * 13,
         'c':[np.nan] * 6 + [400] * 7+ [np.nan] * 6,
         'd':[np.nan] * 13 + [300] * 6,
         'e':[3,4,5,6,8,10,
              3,4,5,6,8,5,5
              ,4,5,6,8,10,11]
})
print (df)
      a      c      d   e
0   0.0    NaN    NaN   3
1   0.0    NaN    NaN   4
2   0.0    NaN    NaN   5
3   0.0    NaN    NaN   6
4   0.0    NaN    NaN   8
5   0.0    NaN    NaN  10
6   NaN  400.0    NaN  3
7   NaN  400.0    NaN  4
8   NaN  400.0    NaN  5
9   NaN  400.0    NaN  6
10  NaN  400.0    NaN  8
11  NaN  400.0    NaN  5
12  NaN  400.0    NaN  5
13  NaN    NaN  300.0   4
14  NaN    NaN  300.0   5
15  NaN    NaN  300.0   6
16  NaN    NaN  300.0   8
17  NaN    NaN  300.0  10
18  NaN    NaN  300.0  11
```

please you check first group and second group mean is same ,so in output your code will give mean of group first for second replace with NAn , but i also want mean of second group even its same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'a':[np.nan] * 2 + [0]*4 + [np.nan] * 13,
         'c':[np.nan] * 6 + [400] * 7+ [np.nan] * 6,
         'd':[np.nan] * 13 + [300] * 6,
         'e':[3,4,5,6,8,10,
              11,54,56,46,95,89,45
              ,4,5,6,8,10,11]
})
#print (df)
```

---

```
df1 = df[['a','c','d']]
s = df1.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].fillna(-1)
#create groups by consecutive values
m = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()

#get means per groups with transform and set only last value of group to new column
df['mean_e'] = np.where(~m.duplicated(keep='last') & ~df1.isnull().all(axis=1), 
                        df['e'].groupby(m).transform('mean'), 
                        np.nan)
```

---

```
print (df)
      a      c      d   e     mean_e
0   NaN    NaN    NaN   3        NaN
1   NaN    NaN    NaN   4        NaN
2   0.0    NaN    NaN   5        NaN
3   0.0    NaN    NaN   6        NaN
4   0.0    NaN    NaN   8        NaN
5   0.0    NaN    NaN  10   7.250000
6   NaN  400.0    NaN  11        NaN
7   NaN  400.0    NaN  54        NaN
8   NaN  400.0    NaN  56        NaN
9   NaN  400.0    NaN  46        NaN
10  NaN  400.0    NaN  95        NaN
11  NaN  400.0    NaN  89        NaN
12  NaN  400.0    NaN  45  56.571429
13  NaN    NaN  300.0   4        NaN
14  NaN    NaN  300.0   5        NaN
15  NaN    NaN  300.0   6        NaN
16  NaN    NaN  300.0   8        NaN
17  NaN    NaN  300.0  10        NaN
18  NaN    NaN  300.0  11   7.333333
```

Comment: @its not giving output as i want , its giving mean in top row and all values after this row

Comment: How working `df['e'].groupby(m.cumsum()).transform('mean')` ? What return it?

Comment: if 'a','c','d' column values are NAn its giving e column values in mean_e, it should give nan

Comment: without changing its not possible?

Comment: @Nickel - give me a sec

Comment: thanks its working , but have little problem when mean value of first group and second group is same its only giving mean value of first group and for second group giving nan

Comment: @Nickel - Can you show your problem with data? Be free modify my dataframe. Because not sure if understand what is problem. thank you.

Comment: i want if groups mean is same keep it not drop

Comment: @Nickel - sorry, I have no your data, so not easy understand it. Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: in sample data i changed some values and i wrote problem in recent code , maybe it will help to understand you my problem . sorry for trouble .maybe my question is not clear

Comment: @Nickel - Maybe problem is second group have 7 rows and first 6, so different mean, check `(3+4+5+6+8+10)/ 6` vs `(3+4+5+6+8+5+5)/7`

Comment: got your point , but if in dataframe if group1 and group 2 mean is same for example :group1 mean =10 and group2 mean=10  code is only give mean of group 1 , just removing duplicate

Comment: @Nickel - Are real data confidental?

Comment: but in desired output should get both group means

Comment: @ no its not confidential , but i dont know how to give you real data

Comment: @Nickel - Can you sent me your code and real csv by email in my profile. Also please explain what is srong and how is possible verify correct output.